# boto3 will not upload a binary object to s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-3.6, boto3

I am trying to upload an xls file to s3 using boto3 and python 3.6.  I need to be able to upload from an object in memory not disk.

```
ep = 's3test.xlsx'
portfolio_binary = open(ep, "rb").read()
s3_client.put_object(Body=portfolio_binary, Bucket='test', Key='test/test/test.xlsx')


 raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Body, value: <class '__main__.portfolio_object'>, type: <class 'type'>, valid types: <class 'bytes'>, <class 'bytearray'>, file-like object
```

Comment: In python I was able to convert the binary to string with base64 endcode and decode and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Here's some easier code for you:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3')
client.upload_file('/tmp/hello.txt', 'mybucket', 'hello.txt')
```

Comment: It works that I know but I can't save to dist.  I need to upload from object fro memory